# How to insert record in many to many relationship link table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Current I am working on a hospital management system project. I have two tables doctor and patient and have made a link table Visits between them. Primary Keys of doctor and patient tables respectively are foreign keys of the Visits table. I am able to update the doctors table from my code. Whenever a record is inserted into the patients table, the doctor table is checked to find out whether the allocated doctor exists or not, if doctor exists and insertion is made into the visits table. For this I have created a trigger on Patients Table. Now whenever I try to register patients, the patients table gets updated but the code throws a `MySQLException` with message "Column Count Does Not Match Value Count At Row 1".

Code

```
        this.stmt=this.mycon.createStatement();
         String query_add_patient="insert into patients values    ('"+nic+"','"+name+"','"+address+"','"+city+"',"+age+",'"+dob+"','"+telephone+"');";

        String query_select_employees="select * from employees where employee_type='Doctor' and employee_qualification='"+doctor+"'";
        ResultSet rs=this.stmt.executeQuery(query_select_employees);
        if(!rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "This Doctor is not available in this facility!!!","Admin Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }
        rs.first();
        String pattern = "yyyy-m-d";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String enic=rs.getString("employee_nic");
        System.out.println(enic);
        String query="insert into Visits (patient_nic,employee_nic) values ("+nic+","+enic+")";

        this.stmt.executeUpdate(query_add_patient);
        closeConnection();
        openConnection();
        this.stmt=mycon.createStatement();
        this.stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        return true;
```

Here the statement "insert into visits" causes the problem. I tried to close and open the connection again but that did not work. The structure for my visits table is

Visits

```
  patient_nic (varchar(45)) FK  --> patient.patient_nic
  employee_nic (varchar(45)) FK --> employee-->employee_nic
```

Comment: Have you checked the definition of the table and the values that you inserted http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_MySQL_Error_Invalid_Query_Column_Count_Does_Not_Match_Value_Count.php

Comment: Yes I have done that but that did not work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure the Column Names Each Have a Matching Value and Vice Versa.

E.g

```
  Good
   $query = "INSERT INTO table (first_name, last_name)
      VALUES(Mr,Kyaw)";
   Bad
   $query = "INSERT INTO table (first_name, last_name)
      VALUES(Mr,Kyaw,Thu)"; //can give Column Count Does Not Match Value Count At Row 1 exception
```

Comment: Thank your everyone for your suggestions but I have found the solution.

I had placed a trigger on the visits table and the error was due to an incorrect insert statement in the body of the trigger.

Thanks again for your suggestions.